# How many bytes of data can be stored in a single memory address

Tags: c, memory, gdb

I have learned that a memory is just a collection of bytes storage that are numbered with address  thus I have reached the conclusion that each memory address can stores just one byte of data.

I am currently learning how to use the gdb debugger to examine memory but I'm confused as to how the `x` command of gdb is used. I have also learned that a number can be prepended to the format of `x` command to examine multiple units at the target address and also the default size of a single unit is 4 bytes.

How is it possible that a 4-byte data can be stored at a memory address that can hold only one byte? and also how is it possible that `x/8xb` also works at a given memory address when the whole data can be displayed using only a word (i.e `x/1w`)?

Comment: It's not showing 4 bytes at a single address. It's showing the bytes from addr through addr+3.

Comment: ok so does that mean to examine a memory at a given address, one must use the x/1b? @Barmar

Comment: Yes, or just `x/b` will do it, since `1` is the default repeat count.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal addressable memory is often 8 bits, but it's not always the case. For example, I worked on a system with 32,768 addresses of 16-bit values.

> *How is it possible that a 4-byte data can be stored at a memory address*

They're not. The address is the address of the first byte.

0x11223344 at address 0x1000 on a little-endian system which can address 8-bit values:

```
       +--------+
0x1000 |  0x44  |
       +--------+
0x1001 |  0x33  |
       +--------+
0x1002 |  0x22  |
       +--------+
0x1003 |  0x11  |
       +--------+
```

0x11223344 at address 0x1000 on a big-endian system which can address 8-bit values:

```
       +--------+
0x1000 |  0x11  |
       +--------+
0x1001 |  0x22  |
       +--------+
0x1002 |  0x33  |
       +--------+
0x1003 |  0x44  |
       +--------+
```